# MySQL Workbench Schemas Panel not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a trouble with my MySQL workbench 6.0 (i work on Ubuntu) and when I choose a server instance, instead of the "SCHEMAS" panel it shows the message "No object selected". In the "SQL panel" (main panel), the query `show databases;` works, but I have no list of the databases in the "SCHEMAS" panel.

I have this problem with all my instances and when there is a lot of databases and tables, it's annoying!

Do you have any idea about this problem?
Thanks,

Comment: Strong recommendation: update to latest version (6.2.3 atm).

Answer (score 162):

Have you tried dragging the window boarder just above the "Object Info"
button?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you can't even find this in the help section.

Answer (score 116):

I have the same issue on Mac. I tried to uninstall MySQL, Workbench, but doesn't work.

the solution for me is:

1. quit workbench (very important! must quit workbench first!)
2. in Terminal:

> cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/MySQL/Workbench/
>
> rm wb_state.xml
>
> rm wb_options.xml

which reset workbench setting and configurations

3. start workbench again. everything back to normal

If you are using Windows or Linux. do the same for the below file path

```
Windows %AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\
Linux   ~/.mysql/workbench/
```

Alternatively, If you can see only 2 tabs on the left sidebar namely Object Info and Session at the very top of the sidebar, then you may be able to drag the top of the sidebar to the bottom if you are lucky enough

Comment: Worked latest OSX!

Comment: Make sure to close Workbench before deleting the files. If Workbench is open while deleting the files, it will recreate them when closing the application.

Comment: While this worked for me, the answer by  Wasif Kirmani is better as he provides paths for Windows and Linux, not just MacOS

Comment: Super!!, Worked on macos Catalina, latest

Comment: It helps for MySQL Workbench 8.0 on macOS Big Sur

Comment: Worked on latest OSX!

Comment: It worked like a magic!

Comment: Thanks @MartinCarstens. We must close workbench before deleting these files. It worked.

Answer (score 20):

I was facing the same issue in MacOS and deleting the caches worked for me. But, the path in MacOS is not the same

```
Windows %AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\
OS X    ~/Library/Application\ Support/MySQL/Workbench/
Linux   ~/.mysql/workbench/
```

I deleted the wb_options.xml and wb_state.xml files and restarted Workbench and all was back to normal.

Comment: Worked! my windows locations was `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench`

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue and deleting the cache files worked for me.

I am on windows but it seems the path for Linux is "~username/.mysql/workbench/"

The windows path is "%AppData%\MySQL\Workbench\"

I deleted the wb_options.xml and wb_state.xml files and restarted Workbench and all was back to normal.

More details on the settings and log files here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-configuring-files.html

Comment: 3 years later this worked for me. I am on mac, so to find the two files I simply ran 
 a find command as follows, `sudo find ~ -type f -name wb_options.xml` and then again for the `wb_state.xml`. FWIW in my machine the files are located in `~/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench`. I deleted them and then ta-da! Works like charm. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 7):

It may be a small problem about the UI itself. I said `maybe` because in my case it was just about not having a good UX.

If you can see only 2 tabs on the left sidebar namely `Object Info` and `Session` at the very top of the sidebar, then you may be able to drag the top of the sidebar to the bottom. And ta-da! Your Management schemes appears! They were just sleeping there while I was searching on the web.

Answer (score 4):

Just delete(or move if you want to save them) the config files, on unix it is in ~/.mysql/workbench, don't know where workbench saves it under other platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Close Workbench.
Remove from Windows Task Manager.

In C:\Users[you]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\cache, delete the XXX.columns_widths file where XXX is your connection name.

Open Workbench again, select Schema Priveleges and change window Workbench size and after maximize window.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a different cause & solution, but it might help someone else, so I'll post it. If you are using Laravel Forge, make sure to edit your database user and give it access to the tables that you need to work with. My database wasn't appearing in my panel because I had created a new database after I had already created a user (all in Laravel Forge) so I had to go back and give the user permission to access the new db.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been 5 years but I just experienced the same problem on Mac OS Catalina 10.15 and this is what solved it.

1. Navigate to:

> Preferences > SQL Editor
> and check **Show Metadata and Internal Schemas**

2. Click OK
3. Then refresh the schema list
   Voila, it is back :)

[image]

Comment: I found this answer elsewhere and I'm glad you posted it. I can't believe this worked and the fact this is unchecked by default (for version 8.0.36) is unfathomable!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was attention issue.. Just had to pull down that little grey dot between "Object Info" and "Session". Maybe it helps someone like me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OS X
`~/Library/Application\ Support/MySQL/Workbench/`

I deleted the `wb_options.xml` and `wb_state.xml` files and restarted Workbench and all was back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEari.png)

just move your cursor in sidebar panel (Management,Instance,Performance) whichever is last shown in the panel, once your cursor is change (available for dragging Panel) drag panel below.

Answer (score 0):

delete :

```
  <value type="int" key="DbSqlEditor:SecondarySidebarHidden">0</value>
  <value type="int" key="DbSqlEditor:SecondarySidebarWidth">218</value>
```